# Persisting a header on every print page from IE9

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, vb.net

I have this code at the top of my table and I hoped it would persist my header at the top of every print page but it does not. The resulting table is spread over 3 pages. Is it possible to do this?

```
<div>   
    <table>
        <thead style="display:table-header-group;"><controls:Demoline id="demoLine1" runat="server" /></thead> 
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to control printing of a web page is to create a page specify for printing the content. Some site accomplish this by generating PDF version of the page.